# Remove substring starting and ending with certain word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `http://localhost:4502/mnt/override/apps/cms/components/content/carousel/_cq_dialog.html/content/cms/en/home/kids`

I want to modify this string by removing the part starting with mnt and ending with _cq_dialog.html so that my output will be

```
http://localhost:4502/content/cms/en/home/kids
```

Comment: Then you probably want a regular expression? Something like `/mnt.+?_cq_dialog\.html\//` might work? Using that regex you can replace the matched string with `''`?

Comment: Or maybe using `indexOf` and take, so called, first and last part of url string?

Answer (score 0):

It's not `regex` but using `indexOf` (searching position of desired string).

There is example /explanation in code/ :

```js
//your url
var url='http://localhost:4502/mnt/override/apps/cms/components/content/carousel/_cq_dialog.html/content/cms/en/home/kids';

//get position of /mnt - start position for "deleting"
var st=url.indexOf('/mnt');

//get position of 2nd condition and added 15 (length of 2nd condition)
var en=url.indexOf('_cq_dialog.html/'); en+=15;

//get all strings from very beginnig until start position of 1st condition
var newUrl=url.substr(0,st);

//get strings from end of 2nd condition to end of complete url string
newUrl+=url.substr(en,url.length-en);

//show result
var sp=document.getElementById('sp');
sp.innerHTML=newUrl;
```

```html
<span id="sp"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use **replace( /regex/, substitution )** function:

```
"http://localhost:4502/mnt/override/apps/cms/components/content/carousel/_cq_dialog.html/content/cms/en/home/kids".replace( /mnt.*(?=content\/cms)/, "" )
```

which outputs:

```
http://localhost:4502/content/cms/en/home/kids
```

---

NOTE
**look-ahead** `(?=<PATTERN>)` assertion is new and available in Modern JS.

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression you can locate the subtring that starts with the first isolated `/` and ends with the first occurrence of `.html/`, and replace that with just `/`:

```js
let s = "http://localhost:4502/mnt/override/apps/cms/components/content/carousel/_cq_dialog.html/content/cms/en/home/kids";
let res = s.replace(/\b\/\b.*?\.html\//, "/");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a regex I would go with @evolutionxbox's solution of using a regex of `/mnt.+?_cq_dialog\.html\//` and Javascript's `string.replace` function to replace the string with `''`.

However, if that inner part of the URL is not going to change then you don't need a regex.  You can simply do `input.replace('mnt/override/apps/cms/components/content/carousel/_cq_dialog.html/', '');`

Then, if that inner part of the URL exists it will be removed.